# Why isn't using property definition syntax outside of an object a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, object, syntax-error

I saw this code on [David Shariff's JavaScript quiz](http://davidshariff.com/js-quiz/#q=15) and was surprised it wasn't a syntax error:

```
var bar = 1,
    foo = {};

foo: {
    bar: 2;
    baz: ++bar;
};
foo.baz + foo.bar + bar;
```

How can you use the `name: value` syntax outside of any object like that?

Comment: foo is a label, so technically there is no syntax error, just doesn't make sense

Comment: I think he is referring to the code starting at line 4,  `foo: {`, which, to my untrained eye is weird.  I would understand `foo = {`, but not this.

Comment: Amadan response is pretty clear foo = {} its an object, foo: {..} its a label

Comment: @Patrick Got it.  Haven't used labels in 30 years and don't miss them at all.  Mainly good for programming puzzlers like this one.

Comment: @user949300 couldn't agree more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not `name: value`; this is `label: statement`. See more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). This code is equivalent to:

```
var bar = 1,
    foo = {};

{
  2;
  ++bar;
};

foo.baz + foo.bar + bar;
```

Comment: Will `++bar` be executed?

Comment: @user949300: Sure, why not? We didn't write `break` or `break foo` or anything similar before it. In absence of flow control statements, statements are executed sequentially; first you execute `2;`, which makes little sense but is a valid statement; then you execute `++bar`, which increments `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

The `foo:` in this case is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). It's not very useful in this context since there aren't any nearby loops, but it's valid syntax.

Note that the `foo:` label is not linked to the `foo` variable in any way. The structure that directly follows the label is simply a block containing, strangely enough, two more labels: `bar:` and `baz:` which are followed by two equally plain statements.

As a result, the `foo` object remains empty, and your last line does not work the way you would expect it to. The result of the last line, and therefore the answer to the quiz question, is

> NaN

Comment: How can there be semicolons in the `{ bar: 2; ... }` if it is an object expression? Is it actually just three labels?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: Oh I thought those were commas. In that case, yes, it's actually just three labels.